# How do I print one record perpage in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

I am building an asp.net mvc 3 application and generating reports using iTextSharp

It is my first time using iTextSharp, I have been able to generate the reports
 however here is my problem,

I created a view that I pass to the `viewPdf()` method which converts the view to a pdf format.

However the pdf format has more than one record on the same page, but I need it to print a record per page, i.e not more than more record on a page, each each record is displayed in a detail type layout

How do I achieve this? I have searched google and some forums and have been trying but I'd appreciate some help.

This is what my controller looks like

```
public ActionResult Print(int? ID=null)
{
    viewModel.Applicants=entities.Applicants;
    return this.ViewPdf("", "Print", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: And you didn't find it necessary to show the code for this custom `ViewPdf` action result?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the iTextSharp api, you will find `PdfPage` class, and using `PdfReader.GetPageN()` method you can retrieve just one page of the `PdfDocument`. Then just load that one page into your view. It's a fairly trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using this library:

- [PDF reporting using ASP.NET MVC3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP_MVC_Reporting.aspx)

If true, It uses the "HTMLWorker" class to convert the View's HTML to PDF. So you can not print one record per page with that. It tries to do the work automatically based on the received HTML.